# Set Variable Offsets Based on Empty Cell Location

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up "x" and "y" as vaiable integers where "x" will take the place of 9 and "y" will take the place of 10 in the offset locations listed below.  "x" and "y" will need to change value based on where the first blank cell in the Row corresponding to "t" is.  So if column 9 of the worksheet is blank "x" will equal 9 and "y" will equal 10 and if column 7 is blank "x" will equal 7 and "y" will equal 8 and so on.  I am not really sure where to begin on this one.  Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub FindRow1()
Dim t As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range
Dim e As Range
Dim f As Range
Dim g As Range
Dim h As Range
Dim i As Range
Dim j As Range
Dim k As Range
Dim l As Range
Dim m As Range
Dim n As Range
Dim o As Range
Dim p As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer


With Worksheets("Recap Sheet").Cells
Set t = .Find("Year of Tax Return", After:=.Range("A1"), 
LookIn:=xlValues).Cells
Set c = .Find("12. Total Gross Annual Cash Flow", 
After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues).Cells
Set d = .Find("15. Total Annual Cash Flow Available to 
Service Debt", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues)
Set e = Range(t.Offset(1, 0), c.Offset(-1, 0))
Set f = Range(c.Offset(1, 0), d.Offset(-1, 0))
Set i = Range(t.Offset(1, 9), c.Offset(-1, 9))
Set j = Range(c.Offset(1, 9), d.Offset(-1, 9))
Set k = Range(t.Offset(-1, 9), d.Offset(0, 10))
Set l = Range(t.Offset(1, 9), d.Offset(0, 9))
Set m = Range(t.Offset(1, 10), d.Offset(0, 10))
Set n = Range(d.Offset(0, 9), d.Offset(0, 10))
Set o = Range(c.Offset(0, 9), c.Offset(0, 10))
Set p = Range(t.Offset(0, 9), t.Offset(0, 10))
Set g = c.Offset(0, 9).Cells
Set h = d.Offset(0, 9).Cells
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this? When using Find you should check you've found something before proceeding to avoid an error. Also, I would suggest giving your variables more meaningful names, particularly as you have so many. Could get confusing.

```
Sub z()

Dim t As Range, x As Long, y As Long, n As Long

With Worksheets("Recap Sheet").Cells
    Set t = .Find("Year of Tax Return", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not t Is Nothing Then
        n = t.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)(1).Column
        x = n
        y = n + 1
    End If
End With

End Sub
```